# Kernighan and Ritchie exercise 3.4

Tags: c, kernighan-and-ritchie

In K&R book there is an exercise I am not sure I have well understood:

> "In a two's complement number representation, our version of itoa does not handle the largest negative number, that is, the value of n  equal to
> -(2^(wordsize-1)). Explain why not. Modify it to print that  value correctly, regardless of the machine on which it runs."

The itoa (integer to string) function is the following:

```
void itoa(int n, char s[]){
  int i, sign;

  if ((sign=n)<0)
    n=-n;
  i=0;
  do
    {
      s[i++] = n%10 +'0';
    } while ((n/=10)>0);
  if (sign <0)
    s[i++] = '-';
  s[i] = '\n';
  reverse(s);
}
```

First part of the exercise regards the explaination why for
-(2^(wordsize-1)) the function would fail to do the job.

I think that wordsize should stand for the number of bits used to represent an integer on the machine.

Suppose wordsize = 8. Then the function will fail for - 2 to the 8, the number -128.

The reasoning goes in this way:
-127 is represented as `10000001`, and -127 + (-1) will be

`10000001`  + `11111111` that is `10000000`. This in our two complement notation where we use the first bit to capture the sign of the integer, is equal to the decimal integer -128.

Now, if we try to represent 128 in the two's complement notation, We will get:
`10000000` (-128) would have as two complement value exactly `10000000`. So we should represent 128 with the same 8 bits as -128, and this can't be done.

The problem in the itoa function is related to the line

```
if ((sign=n)<0)
    n=-n;
```

when wordsize = 8 bits and n = 128, then n = -(-128) should, I think, assign to n the value corresponding to `10000000`, and so it will assign -128 and not +128 as we want.

The reasoning should be generalized for every possibile wordsize of bits that one could use in the representation of integer on the machine (so for 8 bits, 16bits, 32 and 64bits for integers).

Am I right in this reasoning? Is this the reason why itoa does not work for that kind of negative values?

The solution I would implement would be this: I add an if condition that checks if n is actually -(2^(wordsize-1)). If it is so, then I consider n = -(2^(wordsize-1)) **-1**. This value can be trasnformed for sure into a positive one. Then after having assigned every value to the array slot, i would check the last slot of the array that contains an integer and increment it by 1. For instance, if my wordsize is 8 bits and n=-128, I would apply itoa to -127, get as final array [-,1,2,7,\0] and i would increment the 3rd element of this array by 1 to get the number I want.

I wanted to ask here if the explanation behind the first task of the exercise was correct.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your reasoning is correct. One solution is to store the absolute value of `n` in an `unsigned int` variable.

Comment: Your analysis is correct, and your solution is a plausible one.  Fortunately, there are no powers of two that end in 0, so you don't have to worry that, after subtracting 1, you'll end up with a number ending in 9 such that your "add one back" code will ever have to perform a carry.